# Check tier price is applied or not to product

Tags: addtocart, tierprice

How can I check whether tier price is applied or not after add product to the cart ?

Comment: can you see in view page,  list of tier prices as : `as low as` you can add more than 1 item or for how many items you gave tier price and check in cart page what price is displaying.

Comment: no I can not see because I make customization to hide that.But there is a tier price.

Comment: no problem,  for how much qty you gave tier prices in backend. add that much quantity and check in cart page.

Comment: That is different as per qty. I can calculate programmaticaly and put condition and check tier price is applied or not.But is there any direct way  to find out ?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood question, i have no idea.

Comment: hi krupali did you find any answser?
if you got answer please share.

Comment: @JenithSamuel please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get applied tier price value using below code :

```
$price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getTierPrice($qty);
```

Comment: great .. this works for magento 2.4 as well